# What is it called? A basin or vessel?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, image-identification

Look at this large bowl-shaped container which is very popular in Asia but not in Western countries. It can be used to contain water or you can wash your hands or face using it.

[image]

In the dictionary,

> **[basin](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/basin?q=basin)**: a large round bowl for holding liquids or (in British English) for preparing foods in; the amount of liquid, etc. in a basin
>
> *a pudding basin*

---

> **[vessel](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/vessel?q=vessel)** ​(old use or specialist) a container used for holding liquids, such as a bowl, cup, etc.
>
> *a Bronze Age drinking vessel*

**What is it called? A basin or vessel?**

Comment: I would call it a _washing-up bowl_. NB I would mean _washing up_ in the British sense of washing the dishes, not the American one of washing oneself. Most British homes have one (the red bowl, not the dipper) in their kitchen sink.

Comment: Wouldn't you expect the **bath tub**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In British English, a fairly large square or round plastic container that can be placed inside a kitchen sink is commonly referred to as a [**(washing-up) bowl**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bowl).

A *[**vessel**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vessel)* would be any hollowed out object that either floats on water, e.g. a *boat*

> **boat**
>   a small vessel propelled on water by oars, sails, or an engine.

or is used to contain liquids such as wine, juice, milk etc, e.g. a *[goblet](https://research.britishmuseum.org/research/collection_online/collection_object_details.aspx?objectId=592484&partId=1)*  is normally an ancient drinking vessel.

> **goblet**
>   a drinking glass with a foot and a stem.

Comment: I think "(washing-up) bowl." is the right word because in Asia, people often wash dishes in it.